# Getting the executed command from FileUtils?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When you pass the `:verbose` flag to a FileUtils command, the command gets printed to STDOUT. Is there a way to capture the command so it can be logged or used elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the source for `FileUtils` it uses the following method for doing its verbose output:

```
def fu_output_message(msg)   #:nodoc:
  @fileutils_output ||= $stderr
  @fileutils_label  ||= ''
  @fileutils_output.puts @fileutils_label + msg
end
```

i.e. it is writing the messages to `@fileutils_output` and by default it is using `$stderr`. There doesn't seem to be a method to alter `@fileutils_output` but you could add one:

```
module FileUtils
  def FileUtils.fileutils_output=(new_out)
    @fileutils_output = new_out
  end
end
```

Then if you wanted to capture the commands into a file you could do:

```
my_fu_log = open('fu_log.log', 'w')
FileUtils.fileutils_output = my_fu_log
# FileUtils operations with :verbose => true here
my_fu_log.close
FileUtils.fileutils_output = $stderr # restore writing to stderr if you want
```

or if you wanted to get them in a string you could do:

```
log = StringIO.new
FileUtils.fileutils_output = log
# FileUtils operations with :verbose => true here
# commands are in log.string
```

Also, there is a module `FileUtils::Verbose` which basically includes `FileUtils` (so has all the same methods) but defaults the options to `:verbose => true` so if you wanted to capture lots of commands you could use this instead of specifying the option each time. (you would need to add the `fileutils_output=` method to this module in the same way as above.)

**Alternatives**

As [Joshua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184212/joshua-cheek) says in the comments below, an alternative is to reassign `$stderr` but as he says this does mean that everything written to stderr (not just by `FileUtils`) is redirected. If all the `FileUtils` operations are happening in one go without anything else in between then this might not be an issue. So something along the lines of:

```
orig_stderr = $stderr # keep reference to original stderr
$stderr = my_fu_log
# use FileUtils here
$stderr = orig_stderr # restore stderr
```

Finally, you could reopen `FileUtils` and override `fu_output_message(msg)` itself if you  need more control.

Comment: That was a great answer. Another thing you could do is redirect $stderr to your own object, then you don't have to open up FileUtils class. Of course, you will catch the results of non FileUtils methods that print to $stderr.

Comment: @Joshua Yep, you're right. I actually started off with that approach by looking at reassigning `$stdout` but when that didn't work (because it's writing to `$stderr` instead) I ended up digging into the `FileUtils` code and coming up with the above.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks very for the clear answer (and for this discussion here!) Just what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

To add to Mike's answer (since I can't comment), I created this wrapper `def` if you want to get the output as a string:

```
def fileutil_out
    out = StringIO.new
    FileUtils.fileutils_output = out
    yield
    return out.string
end

mylog.info fileutil_out { FileUtils.chmod_R(0664, 'file.txt', :verbose => isVerbose) }
```

I ended up not using it since I wanted to revert back to `@fileutils_output ||= $stderr` afterwards.