# How to know whether a FileUtils command was successful?

Tags: ruby

I don't see any return value from FileUtils commands.

I'd like to do something like:

```
really=(gets.chomp=="y")
if really
  success = FileUtils.rm_rf "./PROJECT_#{@name}" #does not work
end
puts "./PROJECT_#{@name} deleted" if success
```

I read the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html) for FileUtils, and also read a "[Getting executed command from ruby FileUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163585/getting-executed-command-from-ruby-fileutils)", but I cannot figure how to use the answer.

Comment: Have you tried `FileUtils.rm_r  "path", :secure => true` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation ( http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-rm_rf ) calls to #rm_rf will not echo anything relevant to the task they are taking. #rm_rf actually calls #rm_r with option :force => true. This options enables the method to ignore the StandardError Exception (which would then communicate you something about the operation or why it is not working). Now, back to why it is failing. As somebody already commented, try with the option :secure => true. More info about this here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-remove_entry_secure . This is probably a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the return value:

```
irb(main):006:0> FileUtils.rm_rf 'test'
=> ["test"]
irb(main):007:0>
```

and check if an exception is raised in case of the directory doesn't exist.

If you need the return value, maybe your only option is to run the command inside ruby, please take a look at [this blog post](http://www.shanison.com/2010/09/01/ruby-capture-output-in-realtime/).

Comment: this return value is simply the argument itself apparently. No exception raised.